# How do we catch common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException without using generic type 'Exception'?

Tags: apex

If there is a scenario where common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException would occur and we want to handle it using try-catch then what would be the most specific type of exception that can be put within the catch block. I don't want to use a generic 'Exception'.

Comment: That looks like a Java exception from the underlying layers so I doubt that you will be a able to catch it in Apex. Better to eliminate it.

Comment: @KeithC  It's kind of a situtaion which is unavoidable for now. I need to bypass it somehow. Does that mean that only the generic type 'Exception' can catch it ?

Comment: I'm saying you will not be able to catch it at all. It amounts to the translation layer between Apex semantics and underlying Java code not handling a condition by translating it into an Apex exception so that the Java exception leaks out. But go ahead and try as I may be wrong. AFAIK there is nothing documented about how this works.